# RCCB at inverter/power backup output

Tags: inverter, mains, leakage-current

This question may be lame but I really need a solution. I am not an electrical engineer but asking this here to get help for my home RCCB setup.

I have an RCCB at the main output and it is working, but there is power backup for the home which is actually bypassing it, for example, if there is a leakage the RCCB will trip but the inverter is bypassing it and giving output.

I tried to put a RCCB for the inverter output but it is not working as the neutral is common to both inverter and mains. Is there any way to fix it without adding another neutral for the inverter?

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic of what you have and how it’s connected.

Comment: @winny sure, let me do it, BTW do you know any good tool to draw electrical diagram?